# How to loop through raw JSON data?

Tags: php, json, loops

How can I loop through the following RAW data with PHP and get this result:

Result:

```
 NAME1 - SONG1
 NAME2 - SONG2
 NAME3 - SONG3
```

RAW Data:

```
{"artist":"NAME1","title":"SONG1","album":null,"royaltytrackid":null,"url":null,"image":"test1.jpg","time":1380910069,"localtime":"11:07 AM"},
{"artist":"NAME2","title":"SONG2","album":null,"royaltytrackid":null,"url":null,"image":"test2.jpg","time":1380909866,"localtime":"11:04 AM"},  
{"artist":"NAME2","title":"SONG3","album":null,"royaltytrackid":null,"url":null,"image":"test3.jpg","time":1380909864,"localtime":"11:04 AM"}
```

Comment: Your JSON seems to be invalid. It should probably be encapsulated in `[...]`

Comment: Is it a problem if the Raw data is in RAW text in a PHP file? Have added the [...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your input data is missing the `[` and `]` around the list, so before you can parse it as JSON, you need to add those:

```
$rawData = <<<EOL
{"artist":"NAME1","title":"SONG1","album":null,"royaltytrackid":null,"url":null,"image":"test1.jpg","time":1380910069,"localtime":"11:07 AM"},
{"artist":"NAME2","title":"SONG2","album":null,"royaltytrackid":null,"url":null,"image":"test2.jpg","time":1380909866,"localtime":"11:04 AM"},  
{"artist":"NAME2","title":"SONG3","album":null,"royaltytrackid":null,"url":null,"image":"test3.jpg","time":1380909864,"localtime":"11:04 AM"}
EOL;

$data = json_decode("[" . $rawData . "]");

foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo $item->artist, " - ", $item->title, "\n";
}
```

outputs:

```
NAME1 - SONG1
NAME2 - SONG2
NAME2 - SONG3
```

Comment: @DannyHearnah: already fixed; sorry, been away from all this PHP unintuitiveness for a while.